# Whatsapp webhook callback endpoint not getting hit immediately

Tags: node.js, express, whatsapp

I am using Whatsapp cloud API. I have configured the webhook with a valid URL. It is working properly. But the issue is that once I receive a message from the business and if I send back a message immediately, the callback URL not getting invoked instantly. It waits for three minutes to invoke the endpoint. And if I wait for 3 minutes after a response and then send a message then it invokes instantly. Not able to find the reason. Nothing in the documentation also. I want to make it faster. For all the messages, the webhook should be triggered instantly.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started This is the documentation I followed.

Any help would be highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

I tried sending back 200 OK for all the requests as per the documentation

My server code looks like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const token = process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN;

// Imports dependencies and set up http server
const request = require("request"),
  express = require("express"),
  body_parser = require("body-parser"),
  axios = require("axios").default,
  app = express().use(body_parser.json()); // creates express http server
// Sets server port and logs message on success
var https = require('https');
var credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(process.env.key),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(process.env.cert),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(process.env.ca, 'utf-8')
}
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(process.env.PORT, async () => {
  console.log("Whatsapp server listening to port: "+process.env.PORT);
  // await mysqlConnector.initializeMySql(app);
  // await redis.initializeRedis();

});
```

And my webhook post method looks like this:

```
app.post("/inbound", async (req, res) => {
  // Parse the request body from the POST
  let body = req.body;

  // Check the Incoming webhook message
  // console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2));

  // info on WhatsApp text message payload: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/webhooks/payload-examples#text-messages
  if (req.body.object) {
    if (
      body.entry &&
      body.entry[0].changes &&
      body.entry[0].changes[0] &&
      body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages &&
      body.entry[0].changes[0].value. Messages[0]
    ) {

      res.sendStatus(200);

       //if the business needs to send a text message
      //async function call to send a text message (It is a promise function that makes API call to the /message endpoint of WhatsApp business API)


       // if the business needs to send an interactive message
      //async function call to send interactive message(promise function)


    //if the business needs to send a template
    //async function call to send message template(Promise function)

}
}
}
```

And the function that send the text message:

```
 sendMessage: async function (message, incomingMessageFrom, outgoingMessageFrom, accessToken) {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
      try {
        axios({
          method: "POST",
          url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/" +
            outgoingMessageFrom +
            "/messages?access_token=" +
            accessToken,
          data: {
            messaging_product: "whatsapp",
            "to": incomingMessageFrom,
            "type": "text",
            "text": {
              "body": String(message)
            }
          },

          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        }).then(response => {
          resolve(response.data)
        });
      } catch (error) {
        //log Error
        resolve("error: " + JSON.stringify(error.message));
      }
    })
  }
```

And the function that sends the template:

```
 sendMessageTemplate: async function (templateName, params, incomingMessageFrom, outgoingMessageFrom, accessToken) {
    await this.bindParams(params, templateName);
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
      try {
        //call bind params
        let data = {
          "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
          "to": incomingMessageFrom,
          "type": "template",
          "template": templates[templateName]
        }
        let url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/" +
        outgoingMessageFrom +
        "/messages?access_token=" +
        accessToken;
        axios({
          method: "POST", // Required, HTTP method, a string, e.g. POST, GET
          url:url,
          data: data,
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        }).then(response => {
          resolve(response.data)
        }).catch(err =>{
          appLogger.logMessage("error","Failed to call template api due to: "+JSON.stringify(err.message),className,"sendMessageTemplate","ADMIN","Server",moduleName);
        });

        appLogger.logMessage("debug","The request data send is: "+JSON.stringify(data),className,"sendMessageTemplate","ADMIN","SERVER",moduleName);
        appLogger.logMessage("debug","The request url send is: "+url,className,"sendMessageTemplate","ADMIN","SERVER",moduleName);
      } catch (error) {
        appLogger.logMessage("error","error occured while sending message template: "+JSON.stringify(error.message),"sendMessageTemplate","ADMIN","SERVER",moduleName);
        //logError
        resolve("error: " + JSON.stringify(error.message));
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: You need to tell where is this code hosted, the 3 mins delay cannot be explained reading the code. It must be something related with the infrastructure you're using; are you using serverless functions somewhere?

Comment: The server is hosted in azure

Comment: is it a vm? or is is a serverless function? (however it's called in microsoft-land). A webhook sent from wa doesn't take 3 mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was sending the 200 status after checking the message body. That was causing the delay. Now I am sending the status immediately whenever the request hits.

```
app.post("/inbound", async (req, res) => {
  // Parse the request body from the POST
  let body = req.body;

  res.sendStatus(200);

  if (req.body.object) {
    if (
      body. Entry &&
      body. Entry[0].changes &&
      body. Entry[0].changes[0] &&
      body. Entry[0].changes[0].value. Messages &&
      body. Entry[0].changes[0].value. Messages[0]
    ) {



      }
}
}
```

Now it is responding quickly

Comment: Hello! I know it's not the same issue, but I'm investigating how to send more than one message with the help of the whatsapp api in nodejs, I dare to ask because I read that it handles the whatsapp webhook issue

Answer (score 0):

If you're using serverless computing platforms for hosting like `vercel` ,`heroku`.There is a cold start to run the function.

> but 3 minutes is pretty much longer compared to normal circumstances.

please update your answer with code and your hosting provider for more help.remove the `API` keys from code.

Comment: The server is hosted in Azure. But when I tried it in my local with ngrok then also the webhook was not getting hit immediately.

Comment: why would you use an object to save all the functions.

Comment: remove all the conditions like ```if (req.body.object) {
    if (
      body.entry &&
      body.entry[0].changes &&
      body.entry[0].changes[0] &&
      body.entry[0].changes[0].value.messages &&
      body.entry[0].changes[0].value. Messages[0]
    ) {}``` and then  add res.sendStatus(200)  if it responds immediately we know something is wrong in your if condition

Comment: Thank you! Your input helped me to solve the issue